# The word "wish" used with clause

Tags: word-usage

Why don't the sentences such as

> I wish I were(was) rich.
>   I wish she were(was) my mother.

contain conjunction?

It seems to me

> I wish **if** I were(was) rich .
>   I wish **if** she were(was) my mother.

are more correct.

Comment: The *if* is embedded in, or already implied by, the act of *wish*ing. Adding it to the sentence creates a tautology.

Comment: In that case, `wish` is identical to `if`. It's subjunctive. If you put `if` there, then it needs other clause to complete sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're on the right track, but using the wrong conjunction.  The conjunction *that* is implied in both sentences:

> I wish *that* I were rich.
>   I wish *that* she were my mother.

This word is commonly left out, since it is understood.

By the way, *were* is correct rather than *was*.  Since you are expressing a hypothetical condition (you are not rich, she is not your mother), you use the subjunctive.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use *if* only if you start a "new" sentence:

> **A:** Hey man, are you buying that car?
>
> **B:** I wish! *If* I had the money I would buy it right away!

I hope this example helps, as it has already been stated it's implied *that*, not *if*. You can find some useful informations [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wish).